# Set background of QMainWindow central widget

Tags: qt, background-color, qmainwindow

Using Qt 4.8.4 on Windows 7 (MSVC 2010) I have a standard `QMainWindow` in my app with a toolbar. I want the toolbar to stay grey, but the central widget should have a white background. Calling `centralWidget->setStyleSheet("background-color: white;")` at first seemed to do the job, but using it with a Designer-generated widget (a `Q_OBJECT`) doesn't. Subsequently I toyed around with various other methods to set a style sheet (also using Designer) to no avail.

To see this effect, add or remove the `Q_OBJECT` line in `test.h`. When it's there, only the label gets a white bg. If `Q_OBJECT` is commented out, the whole central widget is white. Of course, I want the whole area white, but also need `Q_OBJECT`.

Here's the files:

**main.cpp:**

```
#include "test.h"

class testwin : public QMainWindow {
public:
    QWidget     *centralWidget;
    QToolBar    *mainToolBar;

    testwin(QWidget *parent = 0) : QMainWindow(parent) {
        centralWidget = new test(this);
        setCentralWidget(centralWidget);
        mainToolBar = new QToolBar(this);
        this->addToolBar(Qt::TopToolBarArea, mainToolBar);
    };

    ~testwin() {};
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    testwin w;
    w.centralWidget->setStyleSheet("background-color: white;");
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

**test.h:**

```
#include <QtGui>

class test : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT    // remove this

public:
    QLabel *label;

    test(QWidget *parent = 0) {
        resize(400, 300);
        label = new QLabel(this);
        label->setText("Test");
    };
};
```

Status update:

- `setStyleSheet("QWidget { background-color: white; }")` does NOT solve the issue
- I succeed in making every Widget (including popup dialogs) white, but that's not what I want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, the proper answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7276330/qt-stylesheet-for-custom-widget), or alternatively by reading the documentation. I need to implement paintEvent for my test class:

```
class test : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT    // remove this

public:
    QLabel *label;

    test(QWidget *parent = 0) {
        resize(400, 300);
        label = new QLabel(this);
        label->setText("Test");
    };

    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)
    {
        QStyleOption opt;
        opt.init(this);
        QPainter p(this);
        style()->drawPrimitive(QStyle::PE_Widget, &opt, &p, this);
    }

};
```

Also many thanks to 1+1=2 who read the manual for me at [the Qt project forum](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/30473/).

Answer (score 4):

```
w.centralWidget->setStyleSheet("QWidget { background-color: white; }");
```

Comment: doesn't help - same behaviour, white label on grey background :(

Answer (score 3):

There is a better way of doing this.

As you know, every `QMainWindow` has a central widget and by default is named `centralwidget`.

So the best way of solving this issue is changing the background for that widget.

It's pretty simple when we use a style sheet. In this case would be the following one:

```
#centralwidget {
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
```