# Qt - Stylesheet id selector not working

Tags: qt

I have very simple stylesheet that is applied on the application level (`QApplication->setStylesheet`) before first window is created, but the `#LeftSidebar` css rule is not working and the backgound color is not affected. On the opposite the `#Editor` rule works as expected.

What i did wrong? `Sidebar` is just `QWidget` subclass that has one `QPushButton`.

```cpp
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    this->resize(1200, 768);
    QSplitter* splitter = new QSplitter();
    splitter->setObjectName("MainSplitter");
    splitter->setChildrenCollapsible(false);

    Sidebar* leftSidebar = new Sidebar();
    leftSidebar->setObjectName("LeftSidebar");
    splitter->addWidget(leftSidebar);

    QTextEdit* editor = new QTextEdit();
    editor->setObjectName("Editor");
    splitter->addWidget(editor);

    QWidget* central = new QWidget();

    QVBoxLayout* layout = new QVBoxLayout();
    layout->setMargin(0);    
    central->setLayout(layout);

    Header* header = new Header();
    header->setObjectName("Header");

    layout->addWidget(header);
    layout->addWidget(splitter);
    this->setCentralWidget(central);
}
```

**application.css**

```
#LeftSidebar {
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
}

#Editor {
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two good answers in [Qt Stylesheet for custom widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7276330/qt-stylesheet-for-custom-widget):

- one option is to subclass from `QFrame` instead of `QWidget`;
- regarding `QWidget` as it is documented in ["Qt Style Sheets Reference"](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html#qwidget-widget):

> If you subclass from `QWidget`, you need to provide a `paintEvent` for
>   your custom `QWidget` as below:
>
> ```
> void CustomWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)
> {
>     QStyleOption opt;
>     opt.init(this);
>     QPainter p(this);
>     style()->drawPrimitive(QStyle::PE_Widget, &opt, &p, this);
> }
> ```

Comment: This is not an answer. First: it is not necessary to subclass `QFrame` to customize border / background. Second: question is about qss, but not about workarounds.

Comment: @SaZ It is not a workaround. I cite Qt documentation that clearly states if you want to use stylesheet with subclass of `QWidget` you must provide `paintEvent`.

Comment: @OrestHera author is not asking about documentation. There are everything OK with selectors/custom widgets. Anyway, your suggestion about subclassing `QFrame` is wrong. So you should fix or remove your answer. I already provided a correct one in comments.

Comment: @SaZ Your answer is not correct. Setting border does not fix the issue. The correct answer if you directly subclass from `QWidget` you should provide `paintEvent` as documented. In that case qss works as expected.

Comment: @OrestHera you don't need to implement `paintEvent` at all to customize background of any widget. Default implementation wokrs. Author say nothing about custom paint event. His `Sidebar` may be a simple container.

Comment: @SaZ "Sidebar is just QWidget subclass". Try it. I tried that with `Sidebar::paintEvent()` it works, but without it does not work even if you provide border.

Comment: @OrestHera agree, I have similar problems, but with native API inside `QStyle`. For example, custom color for `QPushButton` will not work with Vista style.

Answer (score 0):

You might forget trim the style sheet text. if not, it will read only first line.
Example:

```
QTextStream in(&css_file);
QString strCss = in.readAll();
strCss.trimmed();
setStyleSheet(strCss);
```