# Enable own widget for stylesheet

Tags: qt, qwidget, qtstylesheets, qt5.6, qframe

I want to enable my own widget class for stylesheets, whereat I am **not** talking about `setStyleSheet(qss)`, but selectors in a qss stylesheet. It is understood that I have to replace [the "::" with "--"](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html) in namespaces.

Here ( [Qt Stylesheet for custom widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7276330/qt-stylesheet-for-custom-widget) ) I have found a similar question, but it is > 4 years old. Based on the answer I have some detailed questions:

a) Is the published approach with an overridden `paintEvent` still valid (Qt5.6/5.7), from https://stackoverflow.com/a/8817908/356726

```
void CustomWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)
 {
     QStyleOption opt;
     opt.init(this);
     QPainter p(this);
     style()->drawPrimitive(QStyle::PE_Widget, &opt, &p, this);
 }
```

b) In the same thread ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/22094319/356726 ) it is said, I do not need to override `paintEvent`. Ok, leads me to:
b1) is it harmful to override `paintEvent` anyway, even with `QFrame`?
b2) What is with other base classes, e.g. `QTableView`? What makes `QFrame` having this particular role?

c) <strike>has anybody found an official Qt documentation on that topic. Nice code in a, but where does it come from?</strike> ([here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html))  Honestly I do not understand what it does.

-- Edit --

Daniel has pointed out the source of that magical `paintEvent` snippet [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html) (`QWidget` paragraph). Interesting that the same (*"supports only .."*) is said for `QDialog`, which could mean I have to use the snippet there as well. I fail to understand why they do not add that snippet to the `paintEvent` of `QWidget`as per default.

Comment: a) http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html : "Supports only the background, background-clip and background-origin properties.
If you subclass from QWidget, you need to provide a paintEvent for your custom QWidget as below:" i think it is still valid in Qt5.6/5.7

Comment: Thanks, you have found the original source of that very code snippet. Updated above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Is the published approach with an overridden paintEvent still valid (Qt5.6/5.7)*

- Yes

*In the same thread ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/22094319/356726 ) it is said, I do not need to override paintEvent. Ok, leads me to: b1) is it harmful to override paintEvent anyway, even with QFrame? b2) What is with other base classes, e.g. QTableView? What makes QFrame having this particular role?*

- If you subclass [`QFrame`, it provides its own paint event](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/widgets/qframe.cpp.html#_ZN6QFrame10paintEventEP11QPaintEvent). `QFrame` is not a special case, it applies to all widgets. The default [`QWidget::paintEvent`](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/kernel/qwidget.cpp.html#_ZN7QWidget10paintEventEP11QPaintEvent) does nothing. It's empty. That is why you have to override it and provide your own painting to enable stylesheets when subclassing `QWidget`. It is not harmful to override `QFrame`'s paint event, but you will lose the default behavior unless you call the `QFrame`s implementation.

*Has anybody found an official Qt documentation on that topic. Nice code in a, but where does it come from?*

- [Here are the official
  docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html#list-of-stylable-widgets).
  If you scroll down a little it states: `QWidget` *Supports only the background,
  background-clip and background-origin properties. If you subclass
  from QWidget, you need to provide a paintEvent for your custom
  QWidget as below:*

-

```
void CustomWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)    
{
    QStyleOption opt;
    opt.init(this);
    QPainter p(this);
    style()->drawPrimitive(QStyle::PE_Widget, &opt, &p, this);
}
```

Comment: Any idea why the do not make that `paintEvent`implementation the default for `QWidget`?

Comment: @HorstWalter Because `QWidget` is an empty widget.