# Qt QFrame StyleSheet not working in MainWindow

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qstylesheet

I am struggling with a basic StyleSheet question.  I am trying to apply a stylesheet to a QFrame within a MainWindow, and for some reason, the stylesheet is being ignored.  This seems related to [Qt Stylesheet for custom widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7276330/qt-stylesheet-for-custom-widget) and [Enable own widget for stylesheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37952348/enable-own-widget-for-stylesheet), but I've tried adding a paintEvent and that did not help.  Its gotta be something simple, but I can't see it.  Can anyone help?

main.cpp:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QDebug>

#include "mainwindow.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  MainWindowDef mainWindow;
  mainWindow.show();
  return app.exec();
}
```

mainwindow.h:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QtWidgets>

class MainWindowDef : public QMainWindow {
  Q_OBJECT

public:
  MainWindowDef(QWidget *parent = 0);

protected:
  void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *);
};

#endif
```

mainwindow.cpp:

```
#include <QDebug>

#include "mainwindow.h"

MainWindowDef::MainWindowDef(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent) {

  QFrame *frame = new QFrame;

  QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout;

  QPushButton *button = new QPushButton("Press");
  layout->addWidget(button);

  QString myStyle = QString( "QFrame {"
                 "border: 2px solid green;"
                 "border-radius: 4px;"
                 "padding: 2px"
                 "background-color: red;" 
                 "color: blue;"
                 "}");

  frame->setStyleSheet(myStyle);
  frame->setLayout(layout);
  frame->setAutoFillBackground(true);

  setCentralWidget(frame);
}

void MainWindowDef::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)
{
  QStyleOption opt;
  opt.init(this);
  QPainter p(this);
  style()->drawPrimitive(QStyle::PE_Widget, &opt, &p, this);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured this out.  It was missing a semicolon.

```
"padding: 2px"
```

should say:

```
"padding: 2px;"
```

Sigh.

Comment: And after doing such a good job of writing a MCVE, that's frustrating!

Comment: The lingering question in my mind is whether or not there is any way to kick on debugging messages for the style sheet processing.  I thought the include <QDebug> would produce any automatically generated error messages...