# Qt Style Sheets - Not Applied Background Properties

Tags: c++, css, qt, qt5, qt-creator

I'm trying to create a custom widget (itself containing some child widgets) in *Qt Creator* with *Qt Designer*.

In the designer I set the *styleSheet* property for the derived object `ControlBar` to the following values:

```
QWidget{
    font-family: "Segoe UI";
    font-size: 9;
}
QWidget#ControlBar{
    background-color: #3a3a3a;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #ffffff;
}
```

Everything looks fine now in designer as well as in the preview mode (*Shift+Alt+R*).

My intention now is to create an instance of `ControlBar` at runtime and assign it to the main vertical layout of a `MainWindow` instance:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
:   QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    ControlBar *controlBar = new ControlBar;
    ui->verticalLayout->insertWidget(0, controlBar);
}
```

Albeit the styling works as expected for every single sub-widget of *ControlBar*, the given background color (the *background-color* property of `ControlBar`'s styleSheet in particular) is not applied to the control bar, as well as all the other background-related properties. Instead, the background color and styling of `MainWindow`is used, whereas all the sub-widget-related styling is working as expected.

How can I get rid of this behaviour and make `ControlBar`have it's intended background color?

Comment: You certainly forgot to set the object name: `controlBar->setObjectName("ControlBar");`, however that still does not make it work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`QWidget#ControlBar`refers to any widget with the object name "ControlBar".

1. Your widget does not have that object name.
2. For some reason this does not seem to work when the object name is the same as the class name, except for when the object is the root object.

Hence it it works in the designer and preview, but not as a child of something else.

To solve this, use

```
ControlBar{
    background-color: #3a3a3a;
}
```

instead and make sure to inherit `ControlBar` from `QFrame` and not form `QWidget`. If for some reason you cannot, you have to override the `paintEvent`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8817908/1179842) for the exact code.