# Can't set style sheet for a derived class from QWidget in qt

Tags: c++, css, qt, qwidget

I have a derived class from `QWidget`, let's call it `DerivedWidget`. And I set the `DerivedWidget` in `MainWindow` class as central widget. I want to change the background color for the `DerivedWidget`, I tried many ways, it just will not work.

```
DerivedWidget::DerivedWidget(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
    mBtn = new QPushButton(this); //if I have some other widgets on this, like a QPushButton
    mBtn->setStyleSheet("QPushButton { background-color: red; }"); //it works for the QPushButton on this widget

    //tried three ways below to set the widget bgcolor, none of them works
    //first
    this->setStyleSheet("QWidget { background-color: yellow; }"); //it is not working

    //second
    this->setObjectName("#DerivedWidget");
    this->setStyleSheet("QWidget#DerivedWidget { background-color: yellow; }"); //still not working

    //third
    this->setStyleSheet("DerivedWidget { background-color: yellow; }"); //not working either
}
```

So as you can see, I can change the style sheet for the widgets on the `DerivedWidget`, but just can not change its background color. 
I've also tried to change the `DerivedWidget` bgcolor in `MainWindow` class. Of course, I tried more than those three ways I provied, but the results are still the same. None of those methods worked. If I just create a `QWidget` and set it as central widget in `MainWindow` class, I can easily set bgcolor for that. But why can't I set bgcolor for the derived class?
Why would this happen and how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I solved this problem by re-implementing the `paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)` function` like:

```
void CustomWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)
{
    QStyleOption opt;
    opt.init(this);
    QPainter p(this);
    style()->drawPrimitive(QStyle::PE_Widget, &opt, &p, this);
}
```

More details are here: [Qt Doc](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/stylesheet-reference.html#list-of-stylable-widgets) and [a helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7276330/qt-stylesheet-for-custom-widget).